# jQuery UI. Plus one after setting option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have some problem with setting up option to spinner after initialization.

In HTML it looks like:

```
<input class="spinner" value="1000" data-step="20" />
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.spinner').spinner({
        min: 1,
    });

    $('.spinner').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.is('[data-step]')) {
            var step = $this.attr('data-step');

            $this.spinner('option', 'step', step);

        }
    });
});
```

After setting option my value is 1001.. Why? I tried to set value after this, using `.spinner('value', 1000)`, but it doesn't work to. Help please :)

Example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsY9a/)

Comment: Weirdly if you put the option `min: 0` the value is 1000. Seems like it's adding the minimal value to the initial value.

Comment: @gillesc So why .spinner('value', 1000) works greate, but if first set up option step, it doesn't work

Comment: Of course it will be `1001`. Spinner normalizes the value for you. Otherwise it would be possible to get `0` by stepping down. But since you stated the minimum to be 1 => it adds it to the value so that you don't end up with 0 or 20.

Comment: OH! I undrestood a problem! Yes, i must set min parameter as 0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

min value is `automatically` add to the `input value` when you run the code. So set the `min` value as `0`

```
$('.spinner').spinner({
        min: 0,
    });
```

[JQuery Doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#option-min)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you weren't declaring the attribute `data-step` so it was being set automatically. Here's what I did to make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.spinner').spinner({
        min: 1,
    });
    $('.spinner').attr('data-step',1);

    $('.spinner').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.is('[data-step]')) {
            var step = $this.attr('data-step');

            $this.spinner('option', 'step', step);

        }
    });
});
```

And here is a [jsfiddle showing modification shows it working](http://jsfiddle.net/ChY9J/). Hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why it happens. Spinner normalizes the value for you. Otherwise it would be possible to get 0 by stepping down. But since you stated the minimum to be 1 => it adds it to the value so that you don't end up with 0 or 20.

Check the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/spinner.js#L343) and you will see exactly what happens:

```
_adjustValue: function (value) {
    var base, aboveMin,
    options = this.options;

    // make sure we're at a valid step
    // - find out where we are relative to the base (min or 0)
    base = options.min !== null ? options.min : 0;
    aboveMin = value - base;
    // - round to the nearest step
    aboveMin = Math.round(aboveMin / options.step) * options.step;
    // - rounding is based on 0, so adjust back to our base
    value = base + aboveMin;

    ...
},
```

In your case `base` becomes `1`, `aboveMin` will be `1000`, and as the result `value` will turn into `1001`.